# Why this working regex does not work with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have this type of text:

```
Song of Solomon 1:1: The song of songs, which is Solomon’s.
John 3:16:For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
III John 1:8: We therefore ought to receive such, that we might be fellowhelpers to the truth.
```

I am trying to remove the verse (or metadata if you will) and just get plain text the content. The example text shows three different types of verses (multiword, singleword and roman + word), I thought that it would be easier to detect *from the beginning of each line, anything until "number:number:"*, and then substitute it with "" (empty string).

I tested a regex that seems to work (as I described):

1. First find until "number:number:" excluding it [or: .+?(?=(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:))],
2. And then include the "number:number:" pattern [or: (\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:)]

Which leads to the following regex:

```
.+?(?=(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:))(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:)
```

The regex seems to work fine, you can try it [here](http://regexr.com/3affp), the problem is that when I try to use the regex with sed it just does not work:

```
$ sed 's/.+?(?=(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:))(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:)//g' testcase.txt
```

It will produce the same text as the input, when it should produce:

```
 The song of songs, which is Solomon’s.
For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
 We therefore ought to receive such, that we might be fellowhelpers to the truth.
```

Any help please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: try::  sed -i 's/.+?(?=(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:))/(\s+)(\d+)(:)(\d+)(:)/g'

Comment: `\s` and `\d` are both PCRE. Standard POSIX sed doesn't know PCRE.

Comment: (Thus, @AlexisPeters, that won't work with many/all versions of sed either).

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp, ...the thing to keep in mind here is that there's not just one syntax for regular expressions. There's original BRE, newer ERE, and then Perl's PCRE (which several programming languages have their own variants on). Standard UNIX tools generally support only BRE or ERE.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Bingo! There is no such thing as a `working regex`, there's just regexps that work in some versions of some tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed  's/.*[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+: *//' file.txt
```

---

If you have only basic posix regexes available, you need to use the following command:

```
sed 's/.*[0-9]\{1,\}:[0-9]\{1,\}: \{0,\}//' file.txt
```

I need to use `\{1,\}` since the `\+` and `\*` operator is not part of the basic posix regex specification.

---

Btw, if you have GNU goodies, you also use `grep`:

```
grep -oP  '.*([0-9]+:){2} *\K.*' file.txt
```

I'm using the `\K` option here. `\K` clears the current match until this point which can be used like a lookbehind assertion - but with a variable length.

Comment: Thank you very much @hek2mgl I marked your answer as the solution to my problem. I found the basic posix regex very useful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F": *" '{print $3}' file
The song of songs, which is Solomon.s.
For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
We therefore ought to receive such, that we might be fellowhelpers to the truth.
```

---

To make it more secure to the `number:number:` use this:

```
awk -F"[0-9]+:[0-9]+: *" '{print $2}' file
The song of songs, which is Solomon.s.
For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
We therefore ought to receive such, that we might be fellowhelpers to the truth.
```

This will also prevent problems with `:` within the text.

Using Adams regex, we can shorten it some.

```
awk -F"([0-9]+:){2} ?" '{print $2}' file
```

or

```
awk -F"([0-9]+:){2} ?" '{$0=$2}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jotne, I liked your solution nevertheless I voted for hek2mgl as the solution since I am limited to sed only, perhaps I should have specified that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp Can you list what system you are on? I have not seen any system that have `sed `  but not `awk`

Comment: Debian Jessie. The problem is not just this, for some unknown reason yet, some lines do not strictly follow the example I explained, some has a CLRF after the verse and on the next line it starts only with ": verse". I still need to figure why this happens, I'm taking the output from another program (diatheke). I need to investigate more this issue.

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp If you post your real problem, I am sure we can solve it using `awk `.  Debian have both `awk` and `sed`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
sed  -r 's/.*([0-9]+:){2} ?//' testcase.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Adam, I liked your solution nevertheless I voted for for hek2mgl as the solution since it included the basic posix regex option which I found it to be very interesting for my needs. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Too many people ask questions without even thinking of saying they are still alive. You're doing well saying thanks in every reply to your posts. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job `cut` was invented to do:

```
$ cut -d: -f3- file
 The song of songs, which is Solomon’s.
For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
 We therefore ought to receive such, that we might be fellowhelpers to the truth.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ed Morton, I liked your solution nevertheless I voted for for hek2mgl as the solution since I am limited to sed only, perhaps I should have specified that. Thanks anyway!